# Pagination with Metaboxes or Custom Fields

Tags: pagination

As you know we use `<!--nextpage-->` code to make pagination a post. Is there any chance to use this pagination with metaboxes or custom fields?

I want this, because I want to add new alternative system to my video streaming site.

For example there will be three custom fields which their names are like that :

Alternative 1 :

Alternative 2 :

Alternative 3 :

After that I will add iframe codes to this fields. Then, when I publish the post, there will be 3 tabs (tabs name will be Alt-1, Alt-2, Alt3) in new post.

When I click Alt-1, it will open video which I added to Alternative 1 field.

When I click Alt-2, it will open video which I added to Alternative 2 field.

When I click Alt-3, it will open video which I added to Alternative 3 field.

Comment: hmmmm I'm not sure what you're asking, you mean you want to display something from post meta but show different things for different pages of the post? No such functionality currently exists out of the box, it would need to be built from scratch. **What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?** Knowing would help enormously. Also note that metaboxes are just a visual UI for custom fields ( custom fields are better known as post meta )

Comment: Hello. Sorry for my bad English. I have edited my post and explained why I want all of these.